# Apps from the same publisher

Tags: windows-8

In iOS app store I can view the details of an app, and then identify the publisher, and then view other apps from the same publisher.

How do I view other apps from the same publisher in Windows 8 app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are at the Metro UI:

Simply type the name of the publisher.

When the Search box appears, click on 'Store' [Key point]

Then browse the list of products by that publisher.  In my example the publisher was jujuba.

[image: Search for a publisher called jujuba]

Comment: So I guess this feature is not available in windows app store but I can instead use the search feature. Unfortunately if the publisher name is generic I will get a lot of irrelevant results. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I see once you get the initial results you can filter by category and newness.

Comment: it doesn't work. try searching for the apps that were published by google. you get lots of other publishers

Comment: @kirill_igum For google apps you may search for "Google Inc", it will give better results.

Comment: @MeBerserk tried it. doesn't work. you get lots of other garbage.